# Changing the Header cart item totals image background css when quantity is added

Tags: magento-1.7, css, header

I have a background image for the cart items totals on the homepage in the header and the quatity is display as a number in the middle of this image. It is an image of a bag in a gold color. I am using css for this background image. I would like it to turn green when the quantity in the cart is 1 or above. What I am wondering is how I can change the background image to another one when an item is added to the cart?

Answer (score 3):

Set a class based on whether the cart contains any items.  For example:

```
<?php $class = $this->getSummaryCount() > 0 ? 'cart-with-items' : 'empty-cart' ?>
<div id="cart-header-block" class="<?php echo $class ?>">
    ...
</div>
```

Then create two different CSS rules - one for each possible state:

```
.empty-cart { background-image: url('gold.png'); }
.cart-with-items { background-image: url('green.png'); }
```

Comment: Great!  I'd appreciate if you could mark this answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark icon).